# XFS and loss of data when power goes down

Tags: linux, power, ext4, xfs

Each time electricity goes down, my desktop (without UPS) loses some temporary information.

- Opera can lose settings, history, cache, or mail accounts (Thanks heavens I was wise to use IMAP). Partially or all together.
- a whole file (complete and save) in Geany appeared empty (and I didn't commit it to Git)
- rhythmbox lost all podcasts subscription data

I'm afraid there are other losses I just didn't see.

What's the reason? A memory files cache, a mem-disk? Or non-atomic file writes in **xfs**? I have Ubuntu 9.10 and **XFS** on both `/` and `/home` partitions.

Is **ext4** safer in such circumstances? I've seen ext3 is faster. Is it as safe as *4?

Given that the apartment I rent is connected to a common bus and 1 safety switch for several apartments, and the neighbors - alone or together - overload it at least once every week, the lights go down often enough for this to be an issue.

Comment: FYI; XFS **is** a journaling filesystem.

Comment: @abc FYI XFS journals metadata for file system integrity only, it does not have block journaling. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Comment: By chance do you have any special performance tuning going on such as `noatime`, disabled write-barriers, or anything else other than vanilla mkfs and mount?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer Updated...

XFS is not a data journaling filesystem, such as ext3 and ext4, it is a [meta-data journaling filesystem.](https://web.archive.org/web/20100716032849/http://students.engr.scu.edu/~lsaki1/papers/XFS.ppt) The result is a trade-off that (usually) favors speed over reliability.

[This article](http://lwn.net/Articles/476263/) has a good discussion of the current state of XFS. When reading, keep in mind all filesystems are compromises between speed and reliability.

Given your lack of control of the situation, you are a good candidate for buying a small UPS.

Comment: I thought of that, but I think the next thing I'll buy is a laptop, and before I'll change the fs type. Desktop becomes more like a pet: requires too much care. :)

Comment: Why did change to xfs, I wonder... I must have read a very biased opinion and trusted it...

Comment: Generally it is a good idea to use what the installation program suggests, unless you really have a very good reason not to.  This ensures that you are using the same as everyone else, which in turn means that errors are found and fixed faster.

Comment: `XFS is not a journaling filesystem...` Wikipedia and the XFS homapge tell me something different...maybe you should elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: I've been using XFS for years. My computer has both crashed and had the power disconnected. The only problem I've ever had with data integrity is a RAID-1 volume becoming unsynchronized. (which was completely unrelated to XFS as that volume was even using ext2).

Comment: My experiences with XFS and power outages have not been so sanguine. The worst case was a little Oracle server, for trail purposes only fortunately, that came up "good" with an FSCK but the database was useless.

Answer (score 6):

XFS is and always has been a journalling file system. It does not truncate files to a zero length and is the base file system for many enterprise storage appliances.

You do need correctly configured hardware (specifically to make sure volatile write caches are correctly handled in your storage with the barrier mount options).

If you see data loss on any file system, please open a bug report with either your vendor or the upstream developers of the specific file system so we can investigate and try to correct any issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have been using XFS on one of our x86 products and people typically just power off the unit w/o proper shutdown.  Across say 8 machines running all week we see at least 2-3 bricking failures, ie the unit ceases to boot into the os, per week that look as follows: [note: this is being mounted off of a USB drive to read the details]

```
[  239.962783] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  240.089559] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0562, bcdDevice= 2.08
[  240.090356] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  240.091058] usb 1-2: Product: External
[  240.091426] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: JMicron
[  240.091834] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[  240.150714] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  240.169022] scsi host6: uas
[  240.169401] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  240.179711] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMicron  Tech             0208 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  240.191334] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  242.191630] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] 2000409264 512-byte logical blocks: (1.02 TB/954 GiB)
[  242.192377] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  242.203170] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  242.203644] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 6b 00 00 08
[  242.214115] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  242.225350] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[  242.262196]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
[  242.312725] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[  242.727294] XFS (sda4): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[  242.741473] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
[  242.742939] ext4 filesystem being mounted at /run/media/core/boot supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
[  243.288717] XFS (sda4): Starting recovery (logdev: internal)
[  243.453271] XFS (sda4): Metadata corruption detected at xfs_dir3_leaf_check_int+0x94/0xe0 [xfs], xfs_dir3_leaf1 block 0x5bbe0c8
[  243.454681] XFS (sda4): Unmount and run xfs_repair
[  243.455168] XFS (sda4): First 128 bytes of corrupted metadata buffer:
[  243.455801] 00000000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3d f1 00 00 09 32 6a 96  ........=....2j.
[  243.456562] 00000010: 00 00 00 00 05 bb e0 c8 00 00 00 2b 00 00 4a c5  ...........+..J.
[  243.457353] 00000020: 91 06 78 ff f7 7e 4a 7d 8d 53 86 f2 ac 47 a8 23  ..x..~J}​​​​​​​​.S...G.#
[  243.458139] 00000030: 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 80 00 68 00 00 00 00 00 00  .........h......
[  243.458910] 00000040: 00 00 00 2e 00 00 00 08 00 00 17 2e 00 00 00 0a  ................
[  243.459710] 00000050: 02 7a d9 e1 00 00 03 a8 05 cc 80 d3 00 00 01 f4  .z..............
[  243.460494] 00000060: 08 56 88 2d 00 00 00 b0 0e 33 12 56 00 00 02 e0  .V.-.....3.V....
[  243.461264] 00000070: 0e d7 cd 89 00 00 01 b8 14 a5 56 6a 00 00 01 ec  ..........Vj....
[  243.462043] XFS (sda4): Corruption of in-memory data (0x8) detected at __xfs_buf_submit+0x5e/0x1b0 [xfs] (fs/xfs/xfs_buf.c:1514).  Shutting down filesystem.
[  243.463670] XFS (sda4): Please unmount the filesystem and rectify the problem(s)
[  243.475084] XFS (sda4): log mount/recovery failed: error -117
[  243.475912] XFS (sda4): log mount failed
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for the record, i still frequently see this issue on vms years after...

the bug is not acknowleged by pretty much anyone and most likely comes from idiotic reordering that occur either in the linux vfs layer or possibly in my case in vmware since i've only observed this on vms.

basically the filesystem writes the data to a block and then changes the metadata mapping to point to that block rather than the previously used one, which is then freed.

when operations get randomly reordered in the linux vfs layer in some kind of messy way that involves issuing braind dead reordered transactions while hoping barriers set in the wrong places will help, and additionally using vmware which ignores said barriers, there are little chances things will not end up broken.