# Adding sda1 vs. sda to a linux software raid

Tags: linux, partitioning, software-raid, mdadm

I'm running a Linux md software RAID 6 on several USB hard-drives. Each drive is partitioned to contain one partition of type fd (linux raid). My RAID is built on these partitions, i.e. it uses `sda1`, `sdb1`, `sdc1`, ... as its disks.

I just had the USB controller disconnect one of the drives and it dropped out of the array. I unplugged the drive, plugged it back in and added it back into the array, except that I accidentally typed `mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdc` instead of `mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1` (note the `sdc` vs. `sdc1`).

Mdadm started rebuilding the "new" drive.

When I noticed, I stopped the array and, to my surprise, `fdisk` reported that the partition table on `sdc` was still fine. I restarted the array and this time added `sdc1` back into the array. Mdadm took the drive without complaints and simply marked it as active. No rebuild required... ???

This leaves me with the following questions:

- If I add a drive directly to a linux raid, rather than a partition on the drive, does mdadm notice this and leave the first couple of sectors in the drive unused?
- Or does it even automatically detect that there is a linux raid partition on the drive and defaults to using that?
- Or did the partial rebuild actually destroy the beginning of the data on the drive (wrote it earlier than it should be) and mdadm just didn't detect this when I readded the partition correctly?
- I'm having mdadm check the array right now and it's not complaining about anything. Does this mean all is well???

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately, everything is not well... I can't mount the raid drive any more and xfs_repair is busy trying to find a non-corrupt super-block right now... Let's hope it succeeds... Yay for linux software raid... Zero fault tolerance for user error...

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of which method you use, the disk will retain its master boot record and partition table. This is why your disk appeared intact.

Two further points:

1. XFS is absolute junk. And I say this after many a 18+ hour day recovering XFS based servers. Bin it, pick something good - you'll thank me later. If you want software RAID and a file system, ZFS will accomplish both.
2. USB is horrible for RAID devices, if you want multiple drives in an external array, invest a little and buy yourself an external SATA enclosure for the drives

Comment: To flesh out point 1, see http://superuser.com/questions/84257/xfs-and-loss-of-data-when-power-goes-down